# What action does iam:PassRole api perform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-sam

In the below rule:

```
{
    "Condition": {
        "StringLikeIfExists": {
            "iam:PassedToService": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
        }
    },
    "Action": [
        "iam:PassRole"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/some-role*"
    ],
    "Effect": "Allow"
}
```

---

We are using this rule for cloud formation stack creation of SAM template(`sam deploy`). SAM template has lambda and custom roles for lambda.

What exactly are we saying with the above rule?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In short, the statement says that you can assign role with name that starts with `some-role` only to lambda service.

If you want to assign role to a service such as lambda or EC2, you need to have permission to perform `iam:PassRole` action.

`"iam:PassedToService": "lambda.amazonaws.com"` specifies which service you may pass the role to, in this case to lambda service. For example, with this condition, you will not be able to assign this role to EC2 instance.

While this will work, it would be best to use `StringEquals` instead of `StringLikeIfExists`. First, you don't need to use `like` since there is no variable part in the name of the service. It is simply `lambda.amazonaws.com` and it will stay that way. Second, you are passing this role to a service so the mentioned string will always be present, therefore there is no need to use `IfExists`, this is used in situations where you are specifying multiple actions in a single statement but the condition is applicable only to some of them. In such case, you can use `IfExists` part so that you don't have to break the statement into multiple smaller ones.

So in your case, you can write the condition like this

```
    "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
            "iam:PassedToService": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
        }
    }
```

Comment: So... Does this mean that.... we are able to write this line `Role: !GetAtt SomeLambdaRole.Arn` in SAM template of lambda function properties? because of above rule...`iam:PassRole`

Comment: Yes, the IAM entity that is making the call, which in this case is IAM Role that is assigned to EC2 instance needs to have permission to perform `iam:PassRole` action.

Comment: What is the service name for api gateway? Because I need to give `iam:PassedToService`

Comment: `apigateway.amazonaws.com`